# JSLink for same list view webpart in a page hide some fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, jslink, list-view-web-part

we need to create single jslink file for 2 same list view webparts configured on the same page

here are the rendering rules that is defined

1. First Webpart should have some columns to be shown/some columns should be hidden
2. Second Webpart should have some columns to be shown/some columns should be hidden.

we found out something like this for conditional rendering
ctx.wpq== "WPQ3"

how can we render the view with such condition
any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Can't you create two different js files and add those in JSLink property of each list webpart? And then hide columns according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Sample demo for your reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {

        var overrideCtx = {};
        overrideCtx.Templates = {};
        overrideCtx.Templates.OnPostRender = CustomRender;

        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

    })();
    function CustomRender(inCtx) {
        if (inCtx.wpq.indexOf("WPQ3")) {
            $('table.ms-listviewtable th:nth-child(4)', '#MSOZoneCell_WebPart' + inCtx.wpq + '').hide();
            $('table.ms-listviewtable td:nth-child(4)', '#MSOZoneCell_WebPart' + inCtx.wpq + '').hide();

        }
        else {
            $('table.ms-listviewtable th:nth-child(5)', '#MSOZoneCell_WebPart' + inCtx.wpq + '').hide();
            $('table.ms-listviewtable td:nth-child(5)', '#MSOZoneCell_WebPart' + inCtx.wpq + '').hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```

[image]