# SharePoint 2013 Document Library: Change Default Message When No Documents in Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

I have a document library web part on a page that I would like to change the default message"There are no documents in this view." to something else. The solution needs to be applied to a certain document library web part when there's more that one document library web part on the same page.  I tried everything but was unsuccessful. However, I was able to change the default message for a list when it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CSR](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) for this requirement.

Sample demo:

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
            Templates: {
                Footer: function (ctx) {
                    var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
                    if (rows.length<1)
                        return String.format("<div>There are no documents in this view.</div>");
                    else
                        return String.format("<div></div>"); 
                }
            }
        });
```

[image]

Comment: The solution you provided is great however, it's being applied to all web parts on the page. How can I apply the solution to a particular web part? Perhaps using the Title?

Comment: ctx contains a wpq property, you could use it to identify the list view parent,  check this demo https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/266444/jslink-for-same-list-view-webpart-in-a-page-hide-some-fields